# How to ignore root warnings?

Tags: python, warnings, python-imageio

I generate monochromatic images and save them using `imageio.imwrite`. Every time I save a file I get a following warning:

```
WARNING:root:Lossy conversion from float64 to uint8. Range [-0.24890179009891278, 2.35786261304524]. Convert image to uint8 prior to saving to suppress this warning.
```

I don't care for this "lossy conversion". Everything looks well and works fine.

However, every ~100 generated images I got different warning which I want to catch. Thus I want to ignore the above one.

I tried to ignore it, but even if I call

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter('ignore')
```

beforehand I still get this warning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The library doesn't use the `warnings` module. Instead, it logs a message using the [`logging` framework](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html), by calling the top-level [`logging.warning()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.warning). See the [`imageio.core.util._precision_warn()` function](https://github.com/imageio/imageio/blob/5c8c440a55eb22e0ec8526e47bf405eb84b9a164/imageio/core/util.py#L56-L61):

```
from logging import warning as warn

# ...

def _precision_warn(p1, p2, extra=""):
    t = (
        "Lossy conversion from {} to {}. {} Convert image to {} prior to "
        "saving to suppress this warning."
    )
    warn(t.format(p1, p2, extra, p2))
```

This is... unfortunate, as you can't easily disable this using the `logging` API. Best practice is to use a dedicated named logger for libraries.

As such, it is probably best to *patch* the library no make the above function a no-op:

```
import imageio.core.util

def silence_imageio_warning(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

imageio.core.util._precision_warn = silence_imageio_warning
```

You could also silence *all logging*, adjusting configurion on the root logger. This is not ideal, as you may want to use logging yourself or use third-party libraries that are better behaved.

I've [filed an issue with the project](https://github.com/imageio/imageio/issues/376) to ask them to fix their logging story.

Comment: This is very enlightening for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple workaround/solution to this. The library is using `logging` module and not the `warning` module. One can include these lines in the code to suppress any such root warnings unless it is of severity level ERROR.

```
import logging
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Had it not been a root warning, one could use the following snippet instead.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```